# Sqlite3 .get() function is not working, it says name is not defined. It is throwing an error at line 40 {earn.get()}','{earning_value.get()}

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

```
from curses import window
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
#connect to database
conn = sqlite3.connect("track.db")
c = conn.cursor() #create a cursor.
#table
c.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS calculate
    (
        earn TEXT NOT NULL,
        expense TEXT NOT NULL,
        earning_value REAL NOT NULL,
        expense_value REAL NOT NULL,
        bank_balance REAL NOT NULL
    )
    """)
conn.commit()
#button functions
def submit():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('track.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
```

#Getting error on this line, it says c.execute(f"INSERT INTO calculate VALUES ('{earn.get()}','{earning_value.get()}')") NameError: name 'earn' is not defined

```
    c.execute(f"INSERT INTO calculate VALUES ('{earn.get()}','{earning_value.get()}')")
    c.commit()
    c.close()

window = Tk()
```

#Here is how I am getting user inputs to the DB. But it seems not to be working properly.

```
def earning():
new_window =Toplevel()
new_window.geometry("400x400") #new window size
#entry1
text1 = Label(new_window, text="From where did you earn?")
text1.pack() 
earn = Entry(new_window,textvariable='earn')
earn.pack()
#entry2
text2 = Label(new_window, text="How much did you earn?")
text2.pack() 
earning_value = Entry(new_window,textvariable='earning_value')
earning_value.pack()
submit_button = Button(new_window,text='Submit',command = submit)
submit_button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Fix the indentation of your code on `earning()` function.  Note that `earn` is a local variable inside that function, so it is not accessible in other function.  Also it is better to use *placeholders* in SQL statement to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Indentation is fine only, i played around with the indentation as per your feedback. But it is now throwing an indention error